# Is this a correct application of Monotone convergence theorem

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

This is a simple question on whether I am allowed to apply the Monotone convergence theorem.

Suppose that $(X_i)$ are i.i.d. r.v. with $E(|X_i|)<\infty$ for every $i$ and $E(X_i)=0$.
Let $Y_n=S_n + an$, where $S_n = \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}  X_i $ . I need to compute $\lim E(Y_n)$.

My reasoning is as follows. Because $E(|X_i|)<\infty$ , then SLLN applies, and we have $\lim S_n / n = 0  a.s.$. Now,

$Y_n = n ( S_n / n + a )$, so $lim Y_n = \lim n ( S_n / n + a )= \lim na$

And I note that if $a<0$, then that monotonically goes to $-\infty$, and if $a>0$, that goes to $\infty$ monotonically.
Can I then conclude that $\lim E(Y_n) = E( \lim Y_n ) = \infty$ if $a>0$ and $\lim E(Y_n) = E( \lim Y_n ) = -\infty$ if $a<0$?
Is there something faulty in the reasoning above? The part that worried me the most was that the limit of $Y_n$ was monotonically reached only after having used SLLN to "kill" the $S_n / n$ part. Did I commit a math crime there?

Thanks!!

Comment: You are over-thinking. This does not involve any big theorem like SLLN's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fact that $\frac {S_n} n \to 0$ you cannot conclude that $n (\frac {S_n} n) \to 0$.

$EY_n=nEX_1+na$ since $X_i$'s are ii.d. Now $n(EX_1+a) =0$ for all $n$ is $a =-EX_1$,  $n(EX_1+a) \to \infty$ if $a >-EX_1$ and $n(EX_1+a) \to -\infty$ if $a <-EX_1$.